# R library breaks due to failure in loading dyld

Tags: homebrew, dyld

I have installed `r` with Homebrew and installed the [INLA](http://www.r-inla.org/download) package for spatial analysis.

Unfortunately when using this module I get the following error:

`dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/xz/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.4.1_1/lib/R/lib/libR.dylib
  Reason: Incompatible library version: libR.dylib requires version 8.0.0 or later, but liblzma.5.dylib provides version 6.0.0`

I have already installed the `xz` library with Homebrew which installs `liblzma`, `otool -L /usr/local/lib/liblzma.5.dylib` returns:

`/usr/local/lib/liblzma.5.dylib:
        /usr/local/opt/xz/lib/liblzma.5.dylib (compatibility version 8.0.0, current version 8.3.0)
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1238.0.0)`

This seem to indicate that I have the required version despite the exception raised by `r`.

Any help solving this issue will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: I haven't been able to solve the problem per se, but I decided instead to install the packaged version of R from the CRAN website. The `libR.dylib` from the package version does not seem to depend on `liblzma.5.dylib`. `INLA` then works without error.

Comment: This helped me out with a very similar problem. You should make it an answer, as it will probably be easier to find.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't been able to solve the problem with the Homebrew `r`, but I decided instead to install the packaged version of R from the CRAN website.

The `libR.dylib` from the package version does not seem to depend on `liblzma.5.dylib`. INLA then works without error.

Any answer that manages to use Homebrew `r` should probably be upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

In my case a similar error was fixed by reinstalling xz with the commands below, then reinstalling the r package.

`brew unlink xz`

`brew reinstall xz`